# get simple drop down value in webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is my code in which in want to use dropdownlist but i am unable to call its id: error showing that object require for static method.

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_group where Group_Name=" + drpgovtypelcns1.Selecteditem.Text, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group_Name", prefixText);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            List<string> CityNames = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CityNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            }
            return CityNames;
        }
```

Comment: Your `cmd` doesn't even have a single defined parameter. How did you try to add a parameter value? And on which line you get an error? What is your error exactly? Be more specific.

Comment: i am getting error to call drpgovtypelcns1 value

Comment: What is `drpgovtypelcns1`? Your question getting unclear..

Comment: its dropdownlist id name